# Can we communicate with obd devices using php, If yes than how and if not what web language should be used

Tags: php, obd-ii

I have to make a web app in which we have to get response from obd device (like car speed, temperature, battery, tracker power) and show all that results on website. So, how can we connect to obd devices. Can this be done with php language. I am new to this concept of obd device.

Comment: http://blog.lemberg.co.uk/how-guide-obdii-reader-app-development

Comment: https://github.com/mdlayher/obd